# How can I extract numbers without attributes?

Tags: r

I have the following object which I want to extract the numbers without attributes to a data frame as a column. I tried this, but didn't work:

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, alpha.bar))

Named num [1:66] 0.122 0.125 0.131 0.137 0.138 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:66] "alpha[1]" "alpha[2]" "alpha[3]" "alpha[4]" ...
```

Comment: did you try `as.numeric(alpha.bar)`?

Comment: You could also try unname(alpha.bar)

Answer (score 5):

From `?c`:

> c is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except
>   names, for example to turn an array into a vector. as.vector is a more
>   intuitive way to do this, but also drops names. Note too that methods
>   other than the default are not required to do this (and they will
>   almost certainly preserve a class attribute).

It looks like you want to use,

```
data.frame(as.vector(alpha.bar))
```